# get name of lightning input text

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

How can I get name of input text in lightning ? 
I was able to recover just the value and otherwise I have undefined as result

```
   <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.filtreNameText}" action="{!c.filterChange}"/>
<lightning:input class="CASE" name="input2" value="{!v.filtreNameText}" />
```

ControllerJs

```
filterChange: function(component, event,helper) {
    var Nametxt = event.getParam("value");
    var Nametxxt = event.getSource().get("v.name");
    var Nametxxxt = event.currentTarget ;

    console.log(Nametxt+ " " + Nametxxt + " " + Nametxxxt);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As aura [value change](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:valueChange/documentation) handler simply provides old and new value, easy solution is to use [onchange](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/specification) action of `lightning:input`.

Component code:

```
<!-- Not needed:
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.filtreNameText}" action="{!c.filterChange}"/>
-->
<lightning:input class="CASE" name="input2" value="{!v.filtreNameText}" 
    onchange="{!c.filterChange}"/>
```

Client side controller function:

```
filterChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("value: " + event.getSource().get("v.name"));
    console.log("name: " + event.getSource().get("v.value"));
}
```